Is it possible to clone an App from Chrome sources if it shows most files but no package.json?
I found a react platform that I wanted to break down to further understand it more, and redesign it for a future idea, and it seems to have all required files but I'm not sure, so I'm hoping someone might be able to help, or if I'm missing something.
Under inspect sources:
"Authored" has 2 folders, one is "static" that has all Components, Contexts, Hooks, Pages, Node Modules, App.js, and Index.js in normal react code.
In the src folder, about half the .TS files have code normal code while others show this calling main.js
"<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8......src="/static/js/main.8d0aabed.js"


The main.8d0aabed.js consists of a long line of code, when beautified looks like this:
74207: (e,t,n)=>{
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
value: !0
}),
t.createMintWithAssociatedToken = void 0;
const r = n(82021)
, i = n(47026)
, o = n(76310)
, a = n(33087);
t.createMintWithAssociatedToken = function(e, t) {

The Source Maps all load successfully, is it possible to break down the functions from Main.js to be useable and/or am I able to use the existing Node Modules & code to create something similar?
Same with Package.js, is it possible to use the Node Modules to create one?
Under "Deployed" it has the CSS, Fonts, main.8d0aabed.js, and main.8d0aabed.css
This is the site, if more info is needed: https://solana.defilaunch.app/
I'm not sure if it's even possible, I just see 80% of the code and have been trying for awhile now.
Tried downloading entire platform using ResourceSaver and running in VSCode, but the Main.js throws errors.

It is unlikely to work on the first go. It will likely require a lot of manual labor to get it to work but you can try the following:
Create a new React app with https://create-react-app.dev/ or something similar, and then start adding files starting from the root. For example, index.js has these code:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

For each import try to either add a module from npm or save an additional file:

import React from 'react'; --> npm install @react
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';  --> npm install @react-dom/client
import App from './App'; --> Save App.js
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; --> Save reportWebVitals.js

Keep doing this until you run our of files. In the end, it will most likely be missing something. However, you might be able to get it to work. There is no silver bullet or guarantee, but it is technically possible to reverse engineer the site. You should ask yourself if it is worth it. Using their code for research and creating your implementation could be OK, but a copy-paste could break copyright laws.
